# Topmost View swallows touch events because overlapping

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view

So here's my layout structure:

```
- RelativeLayout (full screen)
  - FrameLayout (full screen)
  - Button (in the middle of the screen)
  - RecyclerView (align parent bottom but with very big padding top to 
    capture the scrolling also in the top of the screen, so it's basically acting like a full screen `RecyclerView`)
```

So yes, the views are overlapping each other.

As of the reason the `RecyclerView` is the topmost view, it captures all the touch events on screen, and swallows them, preventing any touches to "go through it" to the underlying views below it. (Note: by underlying views, I don't mean to the `RecyclerView`'s children but the other `rootview's` children)

I've read tons of stackoverflow posts regarding propagating touch events and preventing swallowing touch events, etc, and even though it seems pretty straightforward task to accomplish, I couldn't achieve the following effect:

I want my `RecyclerView` to capture the touch event, so it will scroll or whatever. but I want the `rootView` to think as that the `RecyclerView` didn't capture the event, and continue pass it to its other children (`rootview`'
s children).

Here's What I've tried to do:

**1**.  Overriding `dispatchTouchEvent` of the `RecyclerView` to do its logic and return false to act as it didn't dispatch its touch event so the rootview will keep iterating for touch through its child views.

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
    return false;
}
```

**What happened:**

The `RecyclerView` still functions but still swallows all touch events (just the same as before)

**2**. Overriding `onTouchEvent` of the `RecyclerView` to do its logic and return false. (Note: I know it doesn't seem as it would be the solution but I tried)

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    super.onTouchEvent(e);
    return false;
}
```

**What happened:**

Same result as in #1

I've made some more tweaks with the same idea, but they didn't work as well, so I'm kinda clueless right now and would love for help of you fellows!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how efficient/valid/nice solution is this, but this is what comes to my mind: what if you listen for touch events in the root view (`RelativeLayout` in your case), and dispatch the touch event to all the children of that layout except for the `RecyclerView`?

```
public class MyRelativeLayout extends RelativeLayout {
    ...

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final boolean intercept = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);

        // getChildCount() - 1, because `RecyclerView` is the last child
        for (int i = 0, size = getChildCount() - 1; i < size; i++) {
            View v = getChildAt(i);
            v.dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent.obtain(ev));
        }

        return intercept;
    }
}
```

This seems like it should work.

Comment: Thank you, just tried your solution and seems to not be working. the `RecyclerView` still captures only the RecyclerView touch events and the other views seem not to be affected by any touches as well unfortunately. I didn't quite understand your purposed solution neither way - This code apply touch events to all of its siblings but without the `RecyclerView`? If so, (even though we saw that it's not the behaviour that happens) it is not the required behavior. I wish the RecyclerView to get touch events, but also the siblings of the root view if they hit the same area of my touch (go through)

Comment: BTW, I must say that it is very weird that after I applied your code to my root view `RelativeLayout`, the `RecyclerView` still captures touch events, I expected it to not capture anything after that interception :O

Comment: Within `onInterceptTouchEvent()` you have ability to see all the touches that this `ViewGroup` dispatches to its children. What happens in your case, is that `ViewGroup` dispatches the touch to the `RecyclerView`, which handles it, thus no other view is given a chance to respond to the touch. What I suggested, was that regardless that the `RecyclerView` handles the touch, you still are manually dispatching that event to the children, except for the `RecyclerView` itself, because it has already consumed it, you do **not** want to dispatch the same event twice.

Comment: Ehm, but if the root view intercepts the touch and manually dispatching it to the children except the RecyclerView, why would it get the touch event anyway? I mean, the root view first gets the touch, intercepts it and dispatches it to the other children only, it just make sense to me that the RecyclerView wouldn't get the touch?

Comment: It doesn't intercept the touch event. It just calls `super` and returns the boolean that `super` has done. So it just mediates/listens for all touches and intercepts none of them.

Comment: Ah, right I missed this one, I understand the logic now, anyway, I tried mitigating the problem understanding why it is not working as it should, I also noticed the even if I make the `RecyclerView` be on part of the screen, the root view interception causes the other children to not behave "smoothly" on some touches (like one of the children is a preview with scale detector and the touches there are not working as good as without the "interception" code :(

Comment: Initially, I thought that my need is pretty basic, but it seems to be problematic and rare situation..

Comment: qq, @idish did you update the xml code to reference the new MyRelativeLayout class?

Comment: @petey Yes I did

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions for you:
The first is simpler but assumes that you want to click on the `Button` and it can *appear above* the `RecyclerView`, if this is the case you can simply change the layout's order:

```
- RelativeLayout (full screen)
  - FrameLayout (full screen)
  - RecyclerView
  - Button (in the middle of the screen)
```

If you need something more general then it can be done like this:

```
recyclerView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int [] pos = new int[2];
                recyclerView.getLocationOnScreen(pos);
                Rect rect = new Rect();
                button.getHitRect(rect);
                if (rect.contains((int) event.getX() + pos[0], (int) event.getY() + pos[1])) {
                    button.onTouchEvent(event);
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

You will need to handle all your views separately, which is not as nice, but it works in my test.

**Note:** if you have added `addOnItemTouchListener`to your `RecyclerView` you will need to add the said functionality to `onInterceptTouchEvent` (or to both places, depends on your items and `RecyclerView`).

Comment: The first solution is a nice idea, but is not working because if I scroll upon the button, the button swallows the touch event as "selected", so the `RecyclerView` doesn't scroll.

Comment: The second solution is interesting and might be working, but my layout is much more complex than the one in the example, so I rather try it as a last resort only

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your problem, however if the goal is to not allow `RecyclerView` to consume any and all touch events, then simply set `android:elevation="1dp"`for the `FrameLayout` and  `Override` `dispatchTouchEvent()` like so:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    Logger.log("CustomFrameLayout : dispatchTouchEvent");
    boolean result = super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);

    ((View) getParent()).findViewById(R.id.recyclerView).dispatchTouchEvent(event);

    return result;                 // This part can be changed according to requirement.
}
```

This may or may not have some undesired side effects, since I just came up with it on my own, however as much as I have checked it does not.

Cases I've tested:

1. Scrolling in RecyclerView : Works.
2. Clicks in RecyclerView Items : Works.
3. Clicks in Children of FrameLayout : Works.

**UPDATE :**

> Why is there any need for elevation for the FrameLayout?

`android:elevation` provides a means for position of z-axis of any layout. As to *why* there is a need to do so, to answer that I'll have to delve deeper and bore you with lengthy explanation (There is already loads of stuff written on it) suffice it to say that `MotionEvent`s trickle down Views following some basic rules: From root to its children, The child to first get the event first (to check if the event belongs to it) *trickles down* on the basis of their position in the *x-y axis* and then on their order in *z-axis* (Top one gets the event first).

---

So In your case when a `MotionEvent` is detected it is passed to the `RelativeLayout` (RootView), which has 3 children, `Button` will be filtered because of the position. Now you have 2 `Views` a `FrameLayout` and `RecyclerView`. A `RelativeLayout`'s bottom-most child comes on top of the *z-axis*, which means `RecyclerView` event will be dispatched to it first (which will naturally consume the event). If however a case arose in which the event was not consumed (your first attempt), the event will be passed on to the next child `View` until there are no more child `View`s left at which point the parent (`RelativeLayout`) will assume the event belongs to itself and call its own `onInterceptTouchEvent()`. During this process if a `View` has consumed the event all the subsequent calls will be passed to it directly (The reason you can only make one of the two either `FrameLayout` or `RecyclerView` *work*).

> All of the above explanation means by the *rulebook* **only one `View` will ever consume the `event`**.

**What I Did**

I simply *elevated* the `FrameLayout` so it would be the *official* receiver of the event. Overrode the `dispatchTouchEvent()` and sent the same event to its neighboring `RecyclerView` too, which thinks the event has been brought to it by regular mode.

Now after all that explanation

> The comment // This part can be changed according to requirement.

A better and possibly error-less method would be

```
boolean result2 = ((View) getParent()).findViewById(R.id.recyclerView).dispatchTouchEvent(event);

return result || result2;
```

So if any of the `Views` have consumed the event the **root** will *think* that it has been consumed too.

Comment: I will be able test your solution in 1 day. Meanwhile, I would like to ask why is there any need for elevation for the FrameLayout? And if the dispatchTouchEvent of the RecyclerView calls the root view's disptachTouchEvent, wouldn't it be an infinite recursion? Because it would call the RecyclerView's dispatchTouchEvent again?

Comment: @idish you seem a bit confused. I am not calling root view's dispatch method but rather **RecyclerView's** dispatch method from **FrameLayout**. As to your other questions I will update the answer.

Comment: I see, this makes more sense now, as to the elevation part, why can't we just override the dispatchTouchEvent method in the RecyclerView and in its implementation do the same as you did but dispatchTouchEvent to the FrameLayout instead, so the whole elevation part is spared? Furthermore, the button is not a child of the FrameLayout, but the root view as described above. My very next question would be: Why can't I override dispatchTouchEvent of the root view and call dispatchTouchEvent to all of its children so each child will just swallow it if the motionEvent matches the hit rectangle?

Comment: @idish You can ofcourse do the same for RecyclerView. I did it because FrameLayout spans to Parent's width and height (MotionEvent may or may not be lost on crossing layout bounds never checked it myself). 2nd query you may not have completed it but I think the answer would be a Button after Lollipop is by default elevated.

Comment: @idish As to your 3rd question, I can't think of any reason why you can't other than it might hog the system (depends on the number of children the root has at the rect, seems unlikely to be great), why don't you try it and let me know if/how it works out.